# Find Matrix that consists of scalar multiples of vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the matrix *A* of the reflection in the line *L* in R<sup>2</sup> that consists of all scalar multiples of the vector: \begin{bmatrix}2\\3\end{bmatrix}

I honestly can't figure out what this question is asking for. Is it the matrix that reflects to the given matrix? I don't know where to start, and can't find this type of problem in my textbook either.

Comment: I believe this is what the question is asking: consider the transformation $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ which transforms a vector in the plane to its reflection across $L.$ Now find the matrix $A$ which represents this transformation. Does that make sense?

Comment: The reflection is going to map $(2,3)$ to itself, and it's also going to map a vector $x$ that is orthogonal to $(2,3)$ to $-x$. A linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is determined by what it does to two linearly independent vectors; does any of this help? Are there missing pieces of information that you think you might need, and if so, why?

Comment: I appreciate your help. How do I know what line the reflection is across? Because the reflections are different depending which line the reflection is over, right? Like how the matrix for a reflection over the y-axis is different from the one for a reflection over the x-axis. The question just says L. I don't know if there is an equation I need to set up, or if I'm just missing something fundamental. I also don't understand what the question means by "all scalar multiples" in this context @leslietownes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every isometry of the plane(=maps from the plane onto the plane that preserve distances between points) is associated with a matrix. Now notice that reflections are also isometry .For a start the matrix

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$

is  reflection in the line $x=0$ as it takes the point $(x,y)$ to $(x,-y)$.Alright so we'll try to find the rotation matrix $B$ that brings the given vector to the line $x=0$ and then compose it with $A$ and again compose it with $B^{-1}$

So, $ \begin{bmatrix}
 cos\theta &sin\theta \\
 -sin\theta & cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 2 \\
3
\end{bmatrix}
  $
must have its y-coordinate $0$ and also since the magnitude of the vector remains unchanged we have

$2cos\theta+3sin\theta=\sqrt{13} \\
-2sin\theta +3 cos \theta =0$

Now solve for $sin\theta $ and $cos\theta$ .Thus you'd have the matrix
$B = \begin{bmatrix}
 cos\theta &sin\theta \\
 -sin\theta & cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}$

and $B^{-1}AB$   is your required reflection matrix

Comment: I don't really understand this. For starters what would θ be in B? I'm still trying to figure out what the question even wants me to find.

Comment: The $\theta$ for which $-2sin\theta +3cos\theta=0$. Maybe you'd get two rotation matrices but both of them would work . You can also choose the one for which $cos\theta$ is positive

Comment: well, I tried that and got θ=56.31 degrees, then plugged that in and tried finding the inverse of B * AB, but just got a crazy matrix that was incorrect. Thank you for trying to explain. I just don't think I understand this topic at all.

Comment: I'll just add some more details

Comment: wait! I take that back! I went back over my math and was more precise with the calculations. I found the correct answer, thank you so much! I still need to study this topic more thoroughly to get a better understanding, but at least I finished my homework. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A vector orthogonal to $(2,3)^t$ is $(-3,2)^t$ which is mapped to its negative while the line is fixed. With respect to the standard basis, you get
$$
(1,0)^t=\frac{2}{13}(2,3)^t-\frac{3}{13}(-3,2)^t\mapsto\frac{2}{13}(2,3)^t+\frac{3}{13}(-3,2)^t=\frac{1}{13}(-5,12)^t\,,\\
(0,1)^t=\frac{3}{13}(2,3)^t+\frac{2}{13}(-3,2)^t\mapsto\frac{3}{13}(2,3)^t-\frac{2}{13}(-3,2)^t=\frac{1}{13}(12,5)^t\,,
$$
i.e. the representation matrix with respect to the standard basis in domain and codomain is
$$
\frac{1}{13}\begin{pmatrix}
-5& 12\\
12&5
\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$